# How to manage competition between record?

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, record, database

sorry for my bad english. I approached recently to programming in Visual C # and am not a expert programmer. After this short introduction, the important thing I need to implement a management competition on a record during editing operations. This means that having two computers at the same time using this software, the first that starts editing a record, have to "lock" the record so when and if, in the second instance of the program, an attempt to change the same record, a standard message will be displayed and the procedure is interrupted.
I actually use MySQL DBMS and the only thing I could do is to lock the record with "START TRANSACTION" until I COMMIT or close the connection. The problem is that I don't know how to check if there is an active transaction or some kind of block to stop the procedure and this means that the second instance of the program is completely blocked until they release the records from the first instance. Solutions? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please, put some spaces in your question, it's hard to read ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general it's a bad design to physically lock a record while a user is working on it. Database locks are supposed to be short. There should be only code execution between starting the transaction and committing it, but absolutely no user interaction.

You can google "Optimistic locking vs. Pessimistic locking" to understand more about the subject.

If you must use pessimistic locking, you will have to implement some sort of a smart software locks instead of database locks. For example, you could add two fields for the Current_Edit_By and Current_Edit_Time. When a user start editing a record, you fill in these fields with the user id and the current datetime. When another user try editing the same record, you check these two fields and if there are values there then you display an error.

Of course you will need to implement a mechanism to clean locked record automatically if the user disconnect from the database without committing the record. Hence the datetime field (To clear locks older than 30 minutes for example, as long as the connection is no longer there).

Comment: If I understand correctly, following your advice, if a user starts editing a record and then are away from the PC for an hour, the block will be automatically canceled and then another user can edit that record.

Comment: If you want the solution bulletproof, you would need to check whether the user who started editing a record still has an active connection to the database. You would only unlock the record if the connection is no longer there. You would have to research how to do this in MySQL as I am not very familiar with it.